# Firefox doesn't show http answer status code and duplicates all AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, firefox, iis, iis-10

Can someone help with FF? It doesn't show AJAX requests' status codes (in F12 dev tools window). Also it duplicates all AJAX calls to server (save something in database and it will be saved twice), but shows that made only one request. The reason is HTTPS connection. All is good by HTTP, but with SSL by HTTPS problem appears again. 
Server is IIS under Win Server 2019.
Also problem can be in null status code. Pages are returned without status code by https. By http it is ok, status 200 is returned and no problem with AJAX duplicate

Comment: Doesn't it happen on other browsers?

Comment: @ChaseChoi Other browsers work fine, problem is only in Firefox and Firefox-like (Tor has the same problem).

Answer (score 1):

So at last I found the answer. In IIS in your page settings you should go to SSL options and there will be radio-butoon what to do with client certificate. Choose "Ignore" ("Accept" was by default) and Firefox starts working. Pages' status codes comes back, no AJAX duplicates.